# Creating for-loop issue

Tags: vba, loops, for-loop, userform

I have a userform with three frames, each frame contains three option buttons which are continiously named meaning: Frame1 = OptionButton 1, 2, 3 / Frame2 = OptionButton 4, 5, 6 / Frame3 = OptionButton 7, 8, 9

I am trying to create a for loop to search through every frame to check if an option button is true or not and if it is true write the caption of that specific option button into a public variable.

My code so far

```
For i = 1 To 7
For z = 1 To 20

If UserForm1.Controls("Frame" & i).Caption = "Amputationstyp" Then
If UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Value = True Then
    Amputationstyp = UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Caption
End If
End If

If UserForm1.Controls("Frame" & i).Caption = "Amputationsseite" Then
If UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Value = True Then
    Amputationsseite = UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Caption
End If
End If

If UserForm1.Controls("Frame" & i).Caption = "Restgliedstabilität" Then
If UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Value = True Then
    Restgliedstabilität = UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Caption
End If
End If

If UserForm1.Controls("Frame" & i).Caption = "Restgliedform" Then
If UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Value = True Then
    Restgliedform = UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Caption
End If
End If

If UserForm1.Controls("Frame" & i).Caption = "Knochenauswüchse" Then
If UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Value = True Then
    Knochenauswüchse = UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Caption
End If
End If

If UserForm1.Controls("Frame" & i).Caption = "Hautkrankheiten (am Stumpf)" Then
If UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Value = True Then
    Hautkrankheiten = UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Caption
End If
End If

If UserForm1.Controls("Frame" & i).Caption = "Muskeltonus" Then
If UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Value = True Then
    Muskeltonus = UserForm1.Controls("OptionButton" & z).Caption
End If
End If
Next
Next
```

The problem: I tried to check for the frame caption and only write something in the variable when this condition is met, but the condition is also met, when Option button three is getting checked which then leads to a wrong values in all of the variables. The first if statement doesnt work as it is.

Comment: What is the specific problem you're having?  What happens when you run your code?

Comment: `Debug.Print Me.Controls("OptionButton" & ((i - 1) * 3) + n).Value` where `i` is the frame number, and n is the option button number within the frame

Comment: OK that's a bit different from your initial description...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which takes the frame caption and returns the caption of the selected option within that frame:

```vb
Private Sub Tester()

    Amputationstyp = FrameOptionFromCaption("Amputationstyp")
    Amputationsseite = FrameOptionFromCaption("Amputationsseite")
    
End Sub


'get the selected optionbutton caption from inside a frame
'  with the provided caption
Function FrameOptionFromCaption(capt As String) As String
    Dim c As Control, opt As Control
    'loop all controls in the form (inside the Form code module "Me" = the form)
    For Each c In Me.Controls
        'is this a Frame?
        If TypeName(c) = "Frame" Then
            'does the frame's caption match the one provided?
            If c.Caption = capt Then
                For Each opt In c.Controls
                    'if the frame has other types of controls you should
                    '  add a test to only look at optionbuttons...
                    If opt.Value = True Then
                        FrameOptionFromCaption = opt.Caption
                        Exit Function 'done searching
                    End If
                Next opt
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Function
```